# is dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier mandatory to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I use the "famous" boilerplate code that almost everybody uses for handling cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"someCustomCellID"];  
if (cell == nil)  // nothing to recycle from the queue: create a new cell
```

but this give me lots of problems 'cause my cells contains images that I load async and the two functionalities (dequeueing and async load) often conflict. So I try creating every time a new cell and it works pretty well and fast.
But I have a doubt: should I still call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier to free the memory even if I ignore the returned value and create the cells each time?
I suppose the cells not used anymore are automatically deallocated (as they should be), but I wonder if the caching queue may require the explicit "free" with the dequeue call...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is not designed to prevent memory leaks but it is designed for performance (one way is by reducing memory usage). When using the dequeue method, scrolling a table view will be much smoother when there are several rows of data. I would recommend you get your async loading to work with the dequeue method, especially if you see any lag while scrolling. If you would like an example of how to do this see [Apple's LaxyTableImages Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). If you do, however, determine that you do not want to reuse cells, then simply pass `nil` as the `reuseIdentifier` when creating you cells.

Comment: actually not reusing cells is smoother! I try with 1K cells. The problem with async load is that you could end to load the image in the wrong cell 'cause it is reused before the background process finish the image processing. To clarify my comment: I'm not saying that dequeueing is wrong (of course is not), just that don't fit with my particular case.

Comment: Generally if you dequeue cells correctly you WILL have a performance gain. Check out the example provided by Apple I've added to the answer.

Comment: may I be wrong (kinda late here now) or that example have the big problem the lazily load ALL the image in memory? If I'm right that solution may potentially have a huge memory impact...

Comment: You can cache the images however you like in project obviously, but that example shows how to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` while downloading images asynchronously, as well as update the correct table row when the download completes.

Comment: I agree is really interesting example and can help me optimize my code (like not load unnecessary cells) but my performance problem is in loading images from files: I used the async load to solve it and the nil reuse id is another interesting tip. But if I load all the images in memory (as may lazily happen with apple example) my app will be faster but also crash ;)

Comment: Do not forget that every view controller has a `didReceiveMemoryWarning` so if you do leave them all in memory, you can listen for that and clear all the images that are not visible. This way your application will not crash and when the user scrolls again they will see the placeholder images while the app downloads the images again. (Or then load from a file cache which would be quicker)

Answer (score 2):

dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier helps keep down the number of times you load an reload things from files or XIB.  If you have a custom cell or cells with non-standard contents, it can be a lot faster to re-use a cell that already has it all setup.

I recall working on something similar, but in our case, we loaded images into Core Data objects asynchronously and had the cell observe the image in that object.  When the image was loaded, the cell was notified and it updated its image view.

When the cell came back out to us via dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier,  we stopped it from observing and set it to observe the next object's image.

Comment: Interesting solution: just wonder if the handling of the notifications can be as "heavy" as re-creating a cell? If you use UINib it's pretty fast...

Answer (score 2):

Just use `prepareForReuse:` in your `UITableViewCell`'s class, to stop the async load, before the cell is used again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to avoid leaks, if you are dynamically allocating cells.

Presumably your asynchronous image loading works something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        ...
    }

    NSURLRequest *request = [self URLRequestForIndexPath:indexPath];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
        completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }];

    return cell;
}
```

That code has a problem.  By the time the completion handler runs, the table view may have reused the cell for a different row!

We need to change the completion block so it looks up the cell for the row when it's ready to set the image:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        ...
    }

    NSURLRequest *request = [self URLRequestForIndexPath:indexPath];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
        completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            if (cell)
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` has nothing to do with preventing leaks. If there is a leak it would be the developers fault and not the fact that they did or did not use that method.

Comment: Indeed. It's not a leak to not use it. Remember a leak is an object that is no longer referenced by anything. By it's very nature, the cells *are* referenced, by the table view, because it's returned if `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is called.

Comment: You right, my problem is very similar, just I load the images from files and not from the net, and the [UIImage imageWithContentOfFile:] is the bottleneck... I'll try to adapt your code and see if I can make it works for my case.

Comment: @Joe When a table view cell goes off screen, the table view puts the cell into a reuse queue.  If you create a new cell every time the table view asks for one, and never pull one from the queue, the queue might grow without bound.  Nowhere is it documented that the table view drains the queue except via `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: I would agree that would affect the peak memory usage, which is where the performance gain essentially comes from, but still it would not be a leak unless the table itself is leaked. And if the reuse feature is not intended to be used you can simply pass nil as the reuseIdentifier when creating a new cell to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method, always. If it returns a cell, use that cell. If it returns nil, then and only then should you create a cell.

If the method is demanding a cell for an image which you have not yet loaded, then you should provide an alternative. Perhaps a UIImageView with a customized, animated progress spinner? Then, when your image arrives, you can use the proper image when necessary.

Do not worry about deallocating cells. Once you give them to the table view, they are the table view's responsibility (at least as far as memory management is concerned).